# Mensaje en Finalizar compra de Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

Actualmente, tengo esta función que me permite agregar un mensaje en la pagina de Finalizar compra en Woocommerce, ¿Es posible mostrar un mensaje diferente por cada método de pago?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'content_thankyou' );

function content_thankyou() {
    echo '<p>¡Gracias por comprar en nuestra tienda!</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*untested 1*

Con el `order_id` ( que recibe tu función/action ) [buscas la order](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/custom-tracking-code-for-the-thanks-page/) y le preguntas que [método de pago se usó](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order.html#method_get_payment_method)

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'content_thankyou' );

function content_thankyou( $order_id ) {
    echo '<p>¡Gracias por comprar en nuestra tienda!</p>';
    // buscamos la order según el id
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

   // extra check ( si es un objeto y tiene forma de saber su método de pago )
   if ( is_object( $order ) && method_exists( $order, 'get_payment_method' ) ){

    // buscamos el payment method de la order
    $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();

    // imprimimos el payment_method para ver cómo filtrarlo
    echo '<pre>' . PHP_EOL;   
    var_dump( $payment_method );
    echo '</pre>' . PHP_EOL;   

   } // fi extra check

}
```

*untested 2*

También tenés la posibilidad de enganchar un `woocommerce_thankyou` action [por cada payment method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_thankyou_$ORDER-%3EGET_PAYMENT_METHOD), el nombre del action variará según el payment method ( fijate el vardump del ejemplo anterior como son los nombres de tus payment methods ).

Por ejemplo para el method `paypal` sería :

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_paypal', 'content_thankyou' );
```